# How do I use authentication with Awesomium.Net

Tags: wpf, awesomium

I'm using the Awesomium.Net WPF control to display an intranet Silverlight application within a WPF application.

Whilst this works fine in Chrome, with Awesomium, I seem to be having an issue with authentication. I get a notification that authentication is required, but I cannot get past this. I supply the username and password, but get a blank screen.

Has anyone got any idea how to use domain authentication with Awesomium.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that sort of authentication request is trappable via:

```
webView.LoginRequest
```

In the handler, you have options to handle it via the normal modal dialog popup or via code, if I recall correctly - had to muck with it once in the past.

Ref: http://awesomium.com/docs/1_7_rc3/sharp_api/html/E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_LoginRequest.htm